# Calling a non exe (Labview VI) external program into Java

Tags: java, process, runtime, inputstream, labview

I have developed a Labview program and i want Java to trigger it open, i have seen many methods to run external exe applications in Java, is it possible to call an non-exe file with the labview file format .vi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to either:

1. compile your LabVIEW vi either into exe (and then use any standard Java Method to call exe)
2. compile it into a DLL and then use JNI to call it. I would use the first approach unless you are passing huge data chunks, using memory-mapped IO, or  otherwise need fine memory allocation control.
3. or call labview.exe, passing your VI as it's first argument. Set "Run on Open" property in the VI properties. This will require labview development environment present on your target computer